# Error using sockets and soap in java

Tags: java, sockets, soap, client

I have this piece of code that I try to pass a SOAPMessage from a client to a server over sockets(No, I cannot use Connection to do it). With the commented parts on, it works fine However, when I uncomment those parts off, it hangs at the server side on when I call the writeTo method.

Aside:
Even with the commented code on but on the client side, I Thread.sleep instead of close the socket, it hangs on the server side, what's happening?

Client Code:

```
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapRequest = messageFactory.createMessage(),
                soapResponse = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapRequest.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();

        SSLSocket clientSocket = connect( "localhost" );
        OutputStream outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

        // Send Request

        SOAPElement soapElement = soapBody.addChildElement( soapEnvelope.createName( "getPrice" , "ns1", "urn:xmethods-BNPriceCheck" ) );
        soapElement.addChildElement( "isbn" ).addTextNode( "0672324229" );
        soapRequest.saveChanges();

        System.out.println( "\nREQUEST:\n" );
        soapRequest.writeTo( System.out );
        System.out.println();

        soapRequest.writeTo( outputStream );
        outputStream.flush();

        // Recv Response
//      soapPart = soapResponse.getSOAPPart();
//      soapPart.setContent( new StreamSource( clientSocket.getInputStream() ) );
//      soapResponse.saveChanges();
//
//      System.out.println( "\nRESPONSE:\n" );
//      soapResponse.writeTo( System.out );
//      System.out.println();
        clientSocket.close();
```

Server Code:

```
// Initialize
            clientSocket = getClientSocket();
            outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            parameter = getParameter();
            messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();

            // Recv Request

            soapRequest = messageFactory.createMessage();
            soapPart = soapRequest.getSOAPPart();

            soapPart.setContent( new StreamSource( clientSocket.getInputStream() ) );
            soapRequest.saveChanges();

            System.out.println( "\nREQUEST:\n" );
            soapRequest.writeTo( System.out ); // Hangs here
            System.out.println();

            // Send Response
//          soapResponse = messageFactory.createMessage();
//          soapPart = soapResponse.getSOAPPart();
//          soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
//          soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();
//          soapElement = soapBody.addChildElement( soapEnvelope.createName( "getPrice" , "ns1", "urn:xmethods-BNPriceCheck" ) );
//          soapElement.addChildElement( "isbn" ).addTextNode( "0672324230" );
//          soapResponse.saveChanges();
//
//          System.out.println( "\nRESPONSE:\n" );
//          soapResponse.writeTo( System.out );
//          System.out.println();
//
//          soapResponse.writeTo( outputStream );
//          outputStream.flush();
//
//          clientSocket.close();
```

Comment: by "commented parts on" do you mean in both client and server or a particular side?

Comment: commented parts refer to both client and server code

Comment: i am not sure about SOAPMessage in Java but I remember having similar problem in php. For the server to know that the stream has been completed, you have to end your "text" or "call" with a "\n" or "\r". Give it a shot, as this clearly looks like the server cannot identify the end of a stream. I might be wrong though.

Comment: well sorry about that. hope you can find a solution :)

Comment: Why are you using raw sockets if you control both ends of the connection? Just use HTTP